C# .NET httpClient + webproxy ( gives a timeout when using a tunnel vpn connection )
Well when i send this request without connecting to my tunnel internet connection this works super well.( works well gives me the response code )
But when i send this request while i am connected to my vpn this doesnt work it gets a timeout error even if the proxy is dead. ( doesnt work no response code but a timeout )
I dont know why maybe its because my Private vpn host is ( something like : example.hackquest.com ) Its a tunnel connection.
Maybe the proxy is not resolving it but i checked it with other proxy checking applications while my Vpn was turned on ( on those application i get the dead or alive response even if I am using the Vpn )
Is there anything missing in my code. Is there something more to add to fix this issue.
​using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("http://172.121.142.102:3128"),
                UseProxy = true
            };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

            string url = "http://google.com";

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request failed with status code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}

